# Identify the memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

I'm trying to answer some past paper questions that I've been given for exam practice but not really sure on these two, any help be greatly appreciated. (Typed code up from image, think it's all right).

Q1: Identify the memory leaks in the C++ code below and explain how to fix them. [9 marks]

```
#include <string>

class Logger {
    public:
        static Logger &get_instance () {
            static Logger *instance = NULL;
            if (!instance){
                instance = new Logger();
            }
            return *instance;
        }

        void log (std::string const &str){
            // ..log string
        }
    private:
        Logger(){
        }
        Logger(Logger const&) {
        }
        Logger& operator= (Logger const &) {
        }
        ~Logger() {
        }
};

int main(int argcv, char *argv[]){
    int *v1 = new int[10];
    int *v2 = new int[20];
    Logger::get_instance() . log ("Program Started");
    // .. do something

    delete v1;
    delete v2;
    return 0;
}
```

My answer is that if main never finishes executing due to an early return or an exception being thrown that the deletes will never run causing the memory to never be freed. 
I've been doing some reading and I believe an auto_ptr would solve the problems? Would this be as simple as changing lines to?? :

```
auto_ptr<int> v1 = new int[10]; 
auto_ptr<int> v2 = new int[20]; 

v1.release();
delete v1;
```

Q2: Why do virtual members require more memory than objects of a class without virtual members?

A: Because each virtual member requires a pointer to be stored also in a vtable requiring more space. Although this equates to very little increase in space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first answer is correct to get credit, but what the examiner was probably looking for is the freeing up of `Logger *instance`

In the given code, memory for `instance` is allocated, but never deallocated.

The second answer looks good.

Comment: Cheers, how would I go about freeing up the Logger instance? (I know about free and all that if malloc is used but not sure on how it's been done in this example). It wouldn't take place at the end of main would it as that would still cause the same problem as I outlined above or not?

Comment: Not sure if the suggested approach is safe, but you could have another static function which would perform the deallocation using delete, as others have already pointed.

Comment: Luckily it's only an explain so I only need to know the outline of what I'd do. So saying that the memory for the instance isn't deallocated and requires allocating. Thanks!

Comment: requires deallocating* sorry!

Comment: @user2092004: Two options: (a) make it a static instance (`static Logger instance;`) rather than pointlessly throwing away thread-safety and lifetime management by using dynamic allocation; or (b) don't create a global singleton instance in the first place; create one somewhere sensible and pass it to wherever it's needed.

Comment: or simply replace `static Logger *instance` with `static std::auto_ptr<Logger> instance`...

Answer (score 3):

Q1: Note that v1 and v2 are int pointers that refer to an array of 10 and 20, respectively. The delete operator does not match - ie, since it is an array, it should be

```
delete[] v1;
delete[] v2;
```

so that the whole array is freed. Remember to always match `new[] and delete[]` and `new and delete`

I believe you're already correct on Q2. The vtable and corresponding pointers that must be kept track of do increase the memory consumption.

Comment: ohh, the past paper definitely has delete v1 and delete v2 down no square brackets! Someone must have got something wrong then.

Comment: Good eye!  I missed that the delete didn't match

Answer (score 2):

Just to summarize:

1. the shown program has undefined behavior using incorrect form of delete, so talking about leaks for the execution is immaterial
2. if the previous was fixed, leaks wold come from:

   - new Logger(); // always
   - the other two new uses, if subsequent new throws or string ctor throws or the ... part in log throws.
3. to fix v1 and v2 auto_ptr is no good ad you allocated with new[]. you could use boost::auto_array or better make v `array<int, 10>` or at least `vector<int>`. And you absolutely don't use release() and then manual delete, but leade that to the smart pointer.
4. fixing instance is interesting. What is presented is called the 'leaky singleton' that is supposed to leak the instance. But be omnipresent after creation in case something wants to use it during program exit.   If that was not intended, instance shall not be created using new, but be directly, being local static or namespace static.
5. the question is badly phrased comparing incompatible things. Assuming it is sanitized the answer is that a for a class with virtual members instances are (very likely) to carry an extra pointer to the VMT. Plus the the VMT itself has one entry per virtual member after some general overhead. The latter is indeed insignificant, but the former may be an issue, as a class with 1 byte of state may pick up a 8 byte pointer, and possibly another 7 bytes of padding.

Answer (score 1):

instance is never deleted and you need to use operator delete[] in main().

Answer (score 0):

Q1:

few gotchyas -

- singleton pattern is very dangerous, for example it is not thread safe, two threads could come in and create two classes - causing a memory leak, surround with EnterCriticalSection or some other thread sync mechanism, and still unsafe and not recommended to use.
- singleton class does not release they memory, singleton should be ref counted to really act properly.
- you're using a static variable inside the function, even worse than using a static member for the class.

  - you allocate with new [] and delete without the delete[]

I suspect your question is two things:
- free the singleton pointer 
- use delete[]

In general however the process cleanup will clean the dangling stuff..

Q2:

your second question is right, because virtual members require a vtable which makes the class larger